# Autolayout does not give expected output/behavior in iOS 8 app (Interface Builder)

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to achieve a specific layout in the Story Board in iOS 8. ideally, my app would look something like this:

[image]

In Xcode, my setup is the following:

[image]

My constraints are the following for the most important VC (tried to do it manually, but always got an error), which are obtained by clicking "Add Missing Constraints":

[image]

And when I run it in the iOS Simulator it displays the following:

[image]

I know that the "Add Missing Constraints" approach is not the correct approach to solve the problem, but I've tried many approaches that were unsuccessful.

My main question would be: How can I get my VC to look like the desired output (first image in the post)?. I actually got the layout like I wanted to in another app, but it always displays a "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" in the console. I tracked down the error and it comes to this VC (I have a bunch of other VCs in my other app). Also, I was wondering as an aside question if Apple considers this kind of errors to be enough to reject your app submission to the app store.

In addition, I would like to know what are some good books/sources where I can learn Autolayout (since it is kind of my weakness right now in the app dev cycle)? It seems that all the tutorials on youtube or online cover basic stuff, but not as complex as this layout.

Thank you so much for your help!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your image you can set constraints as below

Pin Leading,Trailing,Top spaces along with height

[image]

Same contraints go with your second View

[image]

TableView will be pinned with Top View and bottom Tab Bar along with Leading and Trailing space

[image]

Tabbar will have Leading ,Trailing and Bottom spaces pinned

[image]

I hope you will have the layout without constraint issues just like below

[image]

[edit] If your view is embedded in Tab bar controller everything remains same except you have to pin UITableView bottom space with item below.

Answer (score 1):

you can add constraints as 
1. for blue colored view as top,leading, trailing & height
2. for tab bar bottom, leading,trailing & height
3. & fianlly you give constraint for table view as leading, trailing, top & bottom